# Wake up device when program is run/debugged in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Most of my development devices have OLED displays, so they can't safely have "Stay Awake" enabled under "Developer Options" (I've ruined WAY too many devices using it in the past). But having to continuously keep picking up the device to hit the power button every time I re-launch something within Android Studio is driving me insane.

Is there any way to configure the devices and/or Android Studio to allow the screen to time out and turn off as usual, but automatically turn it back on again whenever I do something via ADB?

For what it's worth, I tried disabling lockscreen security, but launching a program or debugging session via shift-f9 or shift-f10 while the screen of the ADB-connected device is off still fails to turn it on.

Comment: How do you do this now?

Answer (score 1):

Before starting the app, run

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER
```

to wake up the device

Comment: Can we automate this? Eg. add it in gradle script or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

write this code in Oncreate and before Setcontentview :

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

screen will never sleep with this code.